# iTextSharp cannot see the text on a PDF using True Type Fonts

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

This issue is expected as True Type Fonts are an image really, not a font. You would have to use image recognition techniques top accomplish reading it in.
This issue has come up multiple times, and so am placing an answer for it out to the public.

Q: How to parse a PDF when cannot read the font of a PDF for location purposes. EX: An Account number to know page 1, or a page number as "Printed for Duplex for example, not as the document counts it".

I had this issue when managing statements. I needed to know what page I was on, where I was, and what was on it. I began to realize that different print software output different file needs, but you can normally find them in the comments of the PDF output file, you are reading in. For example, I am using "Tray Call ID's" I find in the PDF's I am reading with iTextSharp. An example of this is demonstrated below:

Comment: I see the question in the title but the body of the question doesn't really read as a question so I'm having trouble associating the provided answer with it. Also, when writing a question and answer together, don't make any references to your soon to be written answer in your question. Answers are "aware" of questions but questions should be "aware" of answers.

Comment: I see what you mean. I will update it accordingly. Did it quickly while at work. :(

Answer (score 0):

I first use a simple method like so to test what font type the document is

```
 public void SetFontType()
    {            
       this.PdfReaderContentParser = new PdfReaderContentParser(this.PdfReaderMain);

        //Here we see if we can read the text from the extraction. If not, we know it is a TT font.
        ITextExtractionStrategy iTextExtractionStrategy = this.PdfReaderContentParser.ProcessContent(1, new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy());

        String pdfText = iTextExtractionStrategy.GetResultantText();

        this.TextType = String.IsNullOrEmpty(pdfText) ? TextType.TrueTypeFont : TextType.Default;            
    }
```

When I have established it is not readable, and have encountered a case of the True Type Font, I then do the following to read in the PDF [excluding non-necessary code]

The following code cycles through the annotations to find anything special to search on. In this case I am looking for MT3 type searches, and or a list of items I then use in an override. Every case will be unique, but it sums up the basic concept of stripping out the annotations of the document. This is also briefly explained in iText's documentation.

```
public static Boolean CycleAnnotations(PdfReader reader, int pageIndex, PdfJob job)
        {
            List<string> keys = job.ConfigurationSettings.Where(cfs => cfs.Condition != null).Select(cs => cs.Condition).ToList();

            bool found = CycleAnnotations(reader, pageIndex, keys);

            if (found)
            {
                return found;
            }
            else
            {
                return CycleAnnotations(reader, pageIndex, "MT(TR3)"); //default key
            }
        }

        public static Boolean CycleAnnotations(PdfReader reader, int pageIndex, string key)
        {
            PdfDictionary pdfDictionary = reader.GetPageN(pageIndex);
            PdfArray annots = pdfDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

            if (annots != null)
            {
                foreach (var iter in annots)
                {
                    PdfDictionary annot = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(iter);
                    PdfString content = (PdfString)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annot.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS));
                    if (content != null)
                    {
                        if (Utilities.IsAnnotationFound(content, key))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }

            return false;
        }

        public static Boolean CycleAnnotations(PdfReader reader, int pageIndex, List<string> keys)
        {
            PdfDictionary pdfDictionary = reader.GetPageN(pageIndex);
            PdfArray annots = pdfDictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

            foreach (string keyItem in keys)
            {
                if (annots != null)
                {
                    foreach (var iter in annots)
                    {
                        PdfDictionary annot = (PdfDictionary)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(iter);
                        PdfString content = (PdfString)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(annot.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS));
                        if (content != null)
                        {
                            if (Utilities.IsAnnotationFound(content, keyItem))
                            {
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
```

Hopefully this helps someone, and have a great day!